# How to calculate mod without long division and without a calculator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Instructions:

You don’t need a calculator or long-division to solve this problem (for full credit, your solutions should be as simple as possible). Show how you arrive at your results.

```
(a) Evaluate (170007 − 17003) mod 17

(b) Evaluate 8^126 mod 9

... there are many others...
```

I understand how to do these, but I cannot figure out how to do this without long division AND without a calculator.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint $170007 = 170000 + 7$ and $17003 = 17000 +3$.   And $8126 = 8100 + 27 - 1$.

Comment: You'll find this [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction) helpful for learning more about modular arithmetic.

Comment: And while we're at it, $8126\equiv 8+1+2+6\bmod 9$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

(a)  $170000\equiv17000\equiv0\mod 17$

(b)  $8000\equiv8, 100\equiv1, 20\equiv 2\mod 9$, because $10\equiv1\mod 9$

Comment: I understand they are congruent, but I do not see how you can solve without long division. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, $170007-17003\equiv170000+7-(17000+3)\equiv7-3=4\bmod 17$, and $8126=8000+100+20+6\equiv8+1+2+6\equiv2+6=8\bmod 9$

Comment: For the first, that makes sense. I see how you did that by taking the difference. But what about when there isn't a different to take? For example one of style problems I have is 20000 mod 18. Whats the approach to tackling the 20000 there?

Comment: For that different question, one approach would be to note that $100\equiv10\mod18$ so $1000\equiv100\equiv10\mod18$ and $10000\equiv 10\mod18$, so $20000\equiv20\equiv2\mod 18$

Comment: Also, now that you changed the question from $8126$ to $8^{126}$, the answer is $8^{126}\equiv(-1)^{126}=1\pmod9$

Comment: $20000 = 18000 + 2000 = 18000 + 1800 + 200 = 18000 + 1800 + 180 + 20 = 18000 + 1800 + 180 + 180 + 2\equiv 2 \pmod{18}$.  There is *always* some difference to take.  ... or $20000 = 20*1000 \equiv 2*1000 \equiv 2*100*10\equiv 2*10*10 \equiv 2*100\equiv 2*10 \equiv 20 \equiv 2\pmod{18}$ (because $100 =90 + 10\equiv 10 \pmod {18}$.

Comment: For 8^126 why does it make sense to have -1 congruent to that? I think the concept of congruence here is what I do not understand...

Comment: $8\equiv8-9=-1\pmod9$  see [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432827/kongruens-modulo) for further discussion of congruence

Answer (score 0):

I will only solve the second one; I will leave you to solve the first one.

8126=8100+27-1.  Notice how 8100 and 27 are multiples of 9. The sum, 8127, is also a multiple of 9, which signifies that 8127 mod 9=0. In modular arithmetic , 0-1=8, so 8126 mod 9=8.
(Notice: If you are still confused, draw a circle and draw nine points, writing the numbers 0-8 on the dots clockwise. Now, go to point 0 and go one point anticlockwise. What point do you land on?)

Comment: My apologies, the second one was supposed to be 8^126, and not 8126.

Comment: Then $8\equiv - \pmod 9$ so $8^{126}\equiv (-1)^{126}\equiv 1 \pmod 9$.

Comment: Can you please explain how the -1 came about?

Answer (score 0):

Since $17$ and $9$ are relatively prime to $10$ you can just "cast them out"

$170007= 17*10^{a bunch of zeros} + 7 \equiv 7\pmod {17}$ and $17003= 17*somepoweroften + 3 \equiv 3\pmod {17}$ and so $170007 - 17003 \equiv 7-3 \equiv 4 \pmod{17}$

And $8126 = 81*1000 + 26 \equiv 26 = 27-1 \equiv -1 \equiv 8 \pmod 9$.

......

If you had a harder thing such as $75894302758493275894\pmod {13}$ you could still just "cast out" $13$ wherever you find them:

$75894302758493275894\pmod {13}\equiv$ ($75= 65+10=5*13+10$, $89= 78+11$ etc.) so)

$10110400106100610004 \pmod {13}\equiv$

$10110010100900090004 \equiv$

$10110010100010001004 \equiv$ (and $101-13=89$ so...)

$8908808900008800884 \equiv$

$1101001100001000104 \equiv$

$970870970000870091 \equiv$ ($7*13=91$ so)

$60090060000090000 \equiv$

$8012008000012000 \equiv $

$212000200012000\equiv$

$199000070010700 \equiv$

$61200005009400\equiv$

$9070001100300\equiv$

$1202000970040\equiv$

$1070700060001 \equiv$

$940020008001\equiv$

$30007000201\equiv$

$4000500071\equiv$

$100100006\equiv$

$87087006\equiv$

$9009006\equiv $

$1201206\equiv $

$1071076\equiv $

$940946 \equiv $

$30036 \equiv $

$17010 \equiv $

$4010 \equiv $

$110 \equiv $

$97 \equiv 6 \pmod {13}$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your tester simply wants you to *observe immediately* that the largest multiple of $17$ in both $170007$ and $17003$ are $170000$ and $17000$ respectively, so that the residues modulo $17$ are respectively $7$ and $3.$

Here, you are wanted to see that modulo $9,$ we have $8=-1,$ and it's easy to calculate powers of $-1.$ In this case, since $126$ is even, it follows that $8^{126}=1\pmod 9.$

Comment: So lets take an example where you are not told what the difference is. For the number 8770 mod 3: We start with 8000 + 770 and then what? What I do not understand is how to proceed from there...

Comment: @Maxxie I didn't work with the difference. I reduced *both* numbers individually. As for your example, I find it easy to reduce numbers in base ten modulo $3$ (and $9$ too!) simply by adding their digits and casting away multiples of $3$ (respectively $9$), so your number is equal to $8+7+7=7=1\pmod 3.$ To see why, expand in powers of $10$ and note that $10=1\pmod 3.$